# Add Subview above mainviews layer

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, calayer, subview

I am having trouble adding a subview above the CALayer of its parent view.

I tried to attach an image to show what i mean but i dont have enough reputation so here is a link to the image:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/843/img0219u.png/

Part of the subview is obscured by the parent views border.

How can i make the subview appear over the top of the parent views layer?

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code if it helps:

Code for adding layer:

```
    UIView *student = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
    student.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    CALayer *studentLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    studentLayer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    studentLayer.borderWidth = 5;

    student.layer.borderColor = studentLayer.borderColor;
    student.layer.borderWidth = studentLayer.borderWidth;
```

Code for adding subview:

```
    UILabel *ilp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(-20, -10, 40, 20))];
    ilp.text = @"ILP";
    ilp.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    ilp.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    ilp.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [student addSubview:ilp];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats not possible so far, The best solution i can think of is that add both the subview and its parent view inside another view than its just a matter of reordering two subviews, so that your subview is above the other and its border.

Hope that help!